# Fix Microsoft Teams showing incorrect status: change Offline to Available

Tags: microsoft-teams, bug, status

Microsoft Teams displays wrong status: my keyboard and mouse are active, I am sending messages, but the status is displayed as <kbd>Offline</kbd> (white). I expected the status to be <kbd>Available</kbd> (green). How can I fix the incorrect status?

Wrong status:

[image: Expected status=Available, got status=Offine]

---

I could not fix the issue by manually changing the status to <kbd>Available</kbd>. I clicked on the user icon with the status in the upper-right corner, then clicked on <kbd>Offline</kbd>, and in the drop-down menu selected <kbd>Available</kbd>. This does nothing: the status appears stuck as <kbd>Offline</kbd>:

[image: changing status manually to Available does nothing]

---

I also could not fix the issue by selecting <kbd>Reset status</kbd>:

[image: Reset status does nothing]

**Related:**

- [Microsoft Teams status not updating - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-status-not-updating/dbe50d1b-54b7-4eb6-81e5-d11d77c51ac6)
- [Microsoft Teams - Status issues not updating or displaying the correct status of a user - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257668/microsoft-teams-status-issues-not-updating-or-disp)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest workaround is to restart Microsoft Teams application.

Quit the Microsoft Teams, for example using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and start it again. This resets the status and changes it to <kbd>Available</kbd>, as expected:

[image: Restart Microsoft Teams application to reset the status]